# Audio Jack sensing does not work when putting the laptop on the docking station

Tags: sound, 15.04, headphones, audio-jack, dockstation

I'm using a Dell Latitude with a docking station. Since installing Ubuntu 15.04 on the laptop I have a small problem with the audio jack in the docking station:

I always have a pair of headphones plugged in. When I put the laptop on standby into the station and wake it up, the headphones are not detected. After removing and inserting the plug all works well. This was not an issue with prior versions of Ubuntu.

Any idea how to fix this?